# HTML table not aligning properly next to another table

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align my `table2` to the right using the `align="right"` attribute of table, however, it's not exactly aligning next to the `table1`, as shown in the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/EDSWL/83/). Instead it is getting aligned next to the `Third Heading` which I don't want.

I want `table 1` and `table 2` to be next to one another and then `Heading 3` should come below it.

Another issue, I was trying to resolve is the position of the `Heading 2` with the `float:right` as shown below. It's not going to extreme right.

```css
    .enc-data-table {
        margin: 0 0 45px 0;
    }
    .enc-data-table th {
        font-size: 12pt;
        /*font-weight: 700;*/
        
        padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .enc-data-table td {
        font-size: 12pt;
        padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    h3 {
        width: 50%;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline;
    }
    hr {
        width: 100%
    }
```

```html
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
    <h3 style="float:right">Heading 2</h3>
    <hr/>
    <table class="enc-data-table">
       <tr>
          <th>Location:</th>
          <td >A</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th>Type:</th>
          <td >B</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th>Dates:</th>
          <td >Today</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th>Reason for visit:</th>
          <td >D</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    <table align= "right" class="enc-data-table">
       <tr>
          <th > Number:</th>
          <td >1111</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th >Plan Information:</th>
          <td >1111</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th >Date of service:</th>
          <td >Today</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th >Location Description:</th>
          <td >USA</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    
    <h3>Third Heading <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success add-attribute-ctrl">ADD</button></h3>
    <hr />
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being the douchebag that doesn't answer the question and suggests something but... Have you ever looked at bootstrap ? The grid (col/rows) would easily fix this and you could also take care of responsive at the same time :).

http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? To set the table alignment properly I recommend setting the `th` and `td` elements width separetely!

```
    .enc-data-table th{
        width:20%
    }
    .enc-data-table tr{
        width:80%
    }
```

```css
.enc-data-table {
  margin: 0 0 45px 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.enc-data-table th {
  font-size: 12pt;
  /*font-weight: 700;*/
  padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.enc-data-table td {
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

h3 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}

hr {
  width: 100%
}


/*.enc-data-table th{
    width:20%
    }
    .enc-data-table tr{
    width:80%
    }*/
```

```html
<h3>Heading 1</h3>
<h3 style="float:right">Heading 2</h3>
<hr/>
<table class="enc-data-table" align="left">
  <tr>
    <th>Location:</th>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Type:</th>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Dates:</th>
    <td>Today</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Reason for visit:</th>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table align="right" class="enc-data-table">
  <tr>
    <th> Number:</th>
    <td>1111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Plan Information:</th>
    <td>1111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Date of service:</th>
    <td>Today</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Location Description:</th>
    <td>USA</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>Third Heading <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success add-attribute-ctrl">ADD</button></h3>
<hr />
```

Comment: Yes, I just happened to use inline thing as well here :http://jsfiddle.net/EDSWL/84/

How about the Heading 2 which is not moving to the right?

Comment: I did that here http://jsfiddle.net/EDSWL/86/   (Using your code) but it's not happening.

Comment: @Dan use all of my CSS also, you have also missed out on `<table class="enc-data-table" align="left">`, here is a working example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzzzpuLg/)

Comment: Thanks but this thing is not going extreme right `<h3 style="float:right">Heading 2</h3>` and changing it to `<h3 align="right">Heading 2</h3>` isn't moving it to right at all.

Comment: @Dan if you set the CSS for `th` and `td` you can get the result you want!, use the class `.enc-data-table th{
        width:20%
    }
    .enc-data-table tr{
        width:80%
    }` to position the table properly!

Comment: @Dan Please fix this and share the fiddle then I will help you with the heading tags!